# Update all the sequences

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I had to restore a PostgreSQL 9.6 database from dump files (created with the command `pg_dump --dbname=$DATABASE_URL --username=postgres --file=/usr/postgres-dump --format=directory`).

After the restore (`pg_restore --dbname=$DATABASE_URL --username=postgres /usr/postgres-dump`), all the sequences are set to `1` (i.e. `SELECT last_value FROM issues_id_seq`; returns `1`). However, the `issues` table has thousands of records (the latest record has id = 9331).

From my understanding, I could do something like

```
ALTER SEQUENCE issues_id_seq RESTART WITH 9332;
```

for all the tables in my database.

However, is there a more programmatic way to reset all the sequences based on the actual values of the `id` fields in all the tables?

Comment: There must have been an error during the restore.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It may be. Anyway, I have tried to restore it 3 times and all the times the sequences are set to 1. Therefore, I have to restart the sequences.

Comment: Well, try a fourth time and record all the errors.

Comment: Something is wrong here, `pg_restore` should restore those sequence values. Are all those columns properly defined as `serial`? Do you get any errors during the restore? If you can't figure out where your restore fails, [there is a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62060505)

Comment: +1 to @a_horse_with_no_name but if you only want to change sequence values, you can look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734701/postgresql-change-all-sequences-with-for-loop